# 17.04: using matplotlib with GTK-based backend?

Tags: python, 17.04, gtk-2, matplotlib

On a new 17.04 Ubuntu system, with `python` and `python-matplotlib`, I wanted to plot using the Matplotlib `GTKAgg` or `GTKCairo` backends. This works nicely in 16.04, but is broken in 17.04, as a result of the following:

```
>>> import matplotlib.backends._backend_gdk
ImportError: No module named _backend_gdk
```

But the same command works perfectly in 16.04. Consequently

```
import matplotlib; matplotlib.use("GTKCairo"); 
import pylab; pylab.plot([1,2],[3,4]);pylab.show()
```

works perfectly in 16.04, and fails with the 'no module named' error (as above) on 17.04. I can see that my 17.04 system has the file `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/_backend_gdk.x86_64-linux-gnu.so`, so how is this error arising? Any suggestions for workarounds?

Comment: I also installed `python-matplotlib` using `sudo apt install python-matplotlib` and tried what you did but I was able to make a plot and therefore could not reproduce your error. How did you install matplotlib? Presumably using `apt`/`apt-get`?

Comment: Yes, specifically as recorded here: http://ascend4.org/Building_ASCEND#Ubuntu_17.04 (and under 16.04 below). Did you try the direct import matplotlib.backends._backend_gdk from inside an ipython console on 17.04? And just to check... did you also run matplotlib.use("GTKCairo") on 17.04? Was it a clean system, or had you had other matplotlib/gtk libs installed previously?

Comment: A note: on Ubuntu 18.04, they seem to have permanently(?) removed support for `GTKAgg` and `GTKCairo` from Matplotlib, meaning that you can't use GTK2 for plotting anymore. You have to use GTK3 instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved... while restoring files from my earlier system, I had inadvertently copied an installation of matplotlib in `~/.local/lib/python2.7`, and it was this version, rather than the Ubuntu version that was running and giving the error.